# Java LDAP password authentication

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

The below search term seems to return match if a user simply exists in the active directory:

```
NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> ne = dirContext.search(
                        baseDN,
                        userObjectQuery,
                        new String[] { userName },
                        SearchControls)
```

The userObjectQuery is like `userObjectQuery=(&(sAMAccountName=%u)(objectclass=user))`

Where `%u` above will be substituted by the username.

How do I make sure that the users password also matches and only then return true?

Answer (score 4):

Once you find the user using your search code, you can get the user's full DN with `getNameInNamespace()`

Then you can bind as that full DN and password to authenticate.

Comment: Is it not possible to validate a user's password without binding? For instance we want to have users with bind capability as a special group who can authenticate other less privileged users.

Comment: I have a copy of the user password and just want to ensure that it matches with the password on the AD server. So with the user name I have I want to procure the AD password and then match it with what I have locally. Can that be done with dirContextSearch or is there some other call?

Comment: It would be a very poorly designed LDAP server that let you "acquire" a user's password.  Anybody who could bind could grab all the passwords.  Many LDAP implementations do a one way hash on the password so they don't even keep it.  Binding is the only way I know of to authenticate.